# How to call functions and variables in Component in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

I have two pieces of codes:
index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    ......
    <body>
        <div id="app" v-cloak>
            <div class="pages">
            <page_0 v-if="Page==0"></page_0>
            </div>
            <div class="buttons">
                ......
                <button v-if="isOpen(3)" class="button-blue" @click="Reset()">Reset</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="js/vue.js"></script>
        <script src="vue/page_0.js"></script>
        ......
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var app=new Vue({
                el: '#app',
                data: {
                    Page: 0
                },
                methods: {
                    ......
                    Reset: function(){
                        switch(this.Page){
                            case 0:{
                                //Here I want to call function Reset() in component 'page_0'
                            }
                            ......
                    }
                }
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

page_0.js:

```
Vue.component('page_0',  {
    ......
    methods: {
        Reset: function() {
            //The process of resetting data
        },
        ......
                }
})
```

There comes a problem that I want to call the function Reset() in page_0 when the function Reset in the Vue object 'app' is triggered. I want to know how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, define a reference to the child component

```
<page_0 ref="page0" v-if="Page==0"></page_0>
```

Then you can access its methods directly from the parent

```
this.$refs.page0.Reset();
```

Details in the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements)